# How to disable dates with dateTimePicker AngularJS bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I'm using the [Angular Bootstrap DateTimePicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker).

I'm trying to figure out how to disable specific dates, but nothing is working.

Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: Can you show us what you have already tried?

Comment: Have you checked https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/158 They suggest using beforeRender so you can set minDate and maxDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.
I'm using the beforerender as they suggesting:
I'm taking all objects of current representation (month).
Looking for that specific date then changing that date selectable attribute as false.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me with the Dale Lotts DateTimePicker.

```
    $scope.beforeRender = function ($view, $dates, $leftDate, $upDate, $rightDate) {
        var nowUtc = new Date();
        if ($view === 'day') {
            nowUtc.setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);
        } else {
            if ($view === 'hour') {
                nowUtc.setMinutes(0, 0, 0);
            }
        }

        for (var i = 0; i < $dates.length; i++) {
            if ($dates[i].utcDateValue < nowUtc) {
                $dates[i].selectable = false;
            } else {
                $dates[i].selectable = true;
            }
        }
    }
```